# Are there any disadvantages to having many-column tables

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm planning a database structure which is going to store quite a bit of data. We need to store 50 different 'columns' of data for each item. Adding a timestamp, that gives us 52 columns (and 2 indexes which will be the only way this data is going to be filtered). This database will get a few thousand rows added every day (and never updated), and will be in use for a while.

So my first choice was to shove everything into one table. Got me thinking whether 52 columns is somehow bad or something? I never gave it much thought. Granted the insert code will be irritating but its not like I'm going to write them by hand.

Should I split it into a number of tables (then use Joins or something?), or is there no issue with having tables that large? If it makes a difference I'm using mysql.

ADDED: To make a clarification on how I'll be using the data:

- Sorting and filtering will ONLY be done on indexed columns.
- The data will be used for 'human consumption' at present plans, so we'll always be accessing the entire row (outputting it to a csv or whatever when needed).
- There will be no deletes or updates. There will be a lot of Inserts, and (less frequently) Selects.
- There will be no 'linking' (foreign keys or whatever) of any sorts with other data in the database
- All the data relates to the same thing. There's no 'obvious' way to normalise it, and breaking it into tables would just put categories of sorts into the data and storing them like that.

Comment: I'm voting for this to be moved to [dba.se]: I think you'll get better answers over there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't so much the number of columns that makes a design unfortunate.  It's whether all those columns really belong in that same table.  The data normalization rules have much to say about the consequence of storing data in one table when the data is not tightly related to the key of the table.

It behooves you to learn the normalization rules and what happens when you don't follow them  At some later time, it may also behoove you to learn of cases where deliberate departure from normalization rules may result in a good design.  But you can't learn that until after you have come up to speed on the value of normalizing your table design.

Comment: They all refer tightly to the keys. This is basically storing daily statistics of particular items.
I've read the normalisation rules and if I were to split them, basically it'd keep the same keys. Sp that's not really normalisation.

Comment: Good response. Some people say "normalize" whenever they advise decomposing a table. That's often a misuse of the word. If we're down to pure performance issues, the two relevant things to ask are what the write to read ratio is, or more precisely, how important wasted time is when writing vs reading. And also, when you retrieve data, how often do you want all 50 attributes, or at least half of them, and how often do you just want one attriubte.

Comment: Writes will occur at least a thousand times more frequently. And I'll want all attributes at the present plan. So yeah splitting doesn't seem to be a good idea - I was wondering whether there are some other performance penalties linked with a 'wide' table.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should break it into several table (normalize the table) if it possible. Then, my suggestion is, you should use index to table that you often access. Index can make query become faster. But the disadvantage is, the process when u insert new data become slower.

Comment: I made some clarifications in my main post. Do you still think I should normalise it? (I'm reading about normalisation now)

Comment: I can't really see any way I can 'normalise' it. Since all the data depends solely on the keys and it'll all be needed in one go.

Comment: I think you don't need to normalize it, if you are sure your table can't be break. And just for your information, not all table in database must be normalized, because sometimes big amount of table also can affect the performance of your database :)

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing per-se wrong with having 52 columns in a table.

However, if you will frequently be querying only some subset of those columns, you might find some performance benefit from storing such frequently used columns together in a table of their own without the superfluous columns present.

That said, joining with a secondary table to access the extra columns when required will impair performance (also `INSERT` operations will be slower across two tables), so there is going to be a tradeoff; also note that multiple tables leads to data duplication (at very least the foreign key), and will therefore consume more space overall.

You could benchmark the two approaches to see what difference arises in your own case.  Personally, I'd go with a single table until performance dictates I look elsewhere.

Comment: Given the specifics, I agree one table is best. Just be aware of the [row size limitation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/column-count-limit.html) (of which UTF8 columns take 3 bytes per character).

Answer (score 0):

Having huge table makes seeking and sorting of non-indexed columns more cumbersome and expensive.

It's better to have small and efficient tables.

You can either choose to split your data into multiple 1-to-1 tables, or look into using key/value tables.

Info on key-value table if you're interested: http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/Database-Design-Using-KeyValue-Tables/

Comment: I won't be seeking or sorting by non-indexed columns. Does that change the recommendation any?

Comment: It's probably not that bad if you are so sure that you are only going to be inserting data and never any deletes or updates.

Comment: Just saw your added comments on your original post.  In that case, it seems fine to have a single huge table with that many columns. It usually only becomes an issue when complex operations and seekings are required to be done on the table.